# How to solve SGX Exception 4012?

Tags: c, intel, sgx, enclave

I have a SGX application that runs as a server

When i run the server i get error

`org.whispersystems.contactdiscovery.enclave.SgxException: init_quote_before_create: 0x4012`

checking this url `https://github.com/signalapp/ContactDiscoveryService/blob/main/service/src/main/java/org/whispersystems/contactdiscovery/enclave/SgxException.java`

i learned that the code 4012 means `EPID Provisioning failed due to platform not recognized by backend server`

but why? how to solve it?

I have install the sgx driver 2.11 on ubuntu server 22 and enabled sgx in BIOS/UEFI

My CPU supports SGX1 and 2  `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4310`

cpuid command output:

```
SGX1 supported                           = true

SGX2 supported                           = true
```

When i execute lsmod | grep sgx i get only this:

```
isgx                   57344  0
```

The SPid and APIKey are correct for intel API to work.

I thanks you help in advance